# Is there any way to check how much data/bytes is written in buffer in C

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

is there any way to check how many bytes are written in a buffer at the exact moment? I would like to dynamically set how much data I send via socket using `socket.send()`. Now I have problem, lets say that my file is 200KB and my buffer is set to 24KB so I need to send 9 packages and my output file is 216KB big and not 200KB as input. Is there any way to handle these empty bytes?

Comment: I think it just a simple math calc and loop.

Comment: There is no socket class in standard C++ so you must include information about the library you use. Have you checked the size in _bytes_ of the file you send and the file you received?

Comment: This is just basic maths, isn't it? Keep a count of how many bytes you've written, you already know how many bytes you have to write in total, and how many bytes you can write at one time... so it's just a call to `std::max` .. no?

Comment: Or `std::min` actually :D

Comment: `send` doesn't send a package. Unless you're using UDP, which you probably aren't. Beware that TCP doesn't have packages. You might send 24KB and then recv will decide to only receive 16KB and then receive the other 8KB the next time you call it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socket.send` is unknown to me. I assume you mean using [send(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) on some [socket(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html).

In many cases (think of some [tcp(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) traffic going thru several Wifi routers), the packets could be [fragmented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation). So a given  [send(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) on one side could correspond to *several* [recv(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) on the receiving side and vice versa.

Then you need to manage somehow your packet data (e.g. count and buffer the emitted data, and the received one). In practice, you'll need some documented conventions about them. [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) or [JSONRPC](https://jsonrpc.org/) or [ONCRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call) or [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) could be inspirational.

You'l find libraries which could be helpful. E.g. [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/), [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/). They are open source, so you are allowed to study their source code.

You could also study the source code of well known open source servers, such as [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/), [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), etc... or take inspiration from other open source projects coded in C++, including The [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) or [fish](https://fishsshell.org/) or many others on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/).

You tagged your question both `C` and `C++` but these are very different languages. See [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for more.

BTW, the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) should be helpful. If you compile your C++ code with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), be sure to enable all warnings and debug info, so compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` (and later use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger)

> Is there any way to check how much data/bytes is written in buffer in C

Yes, since both [send(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) and [write(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) (and also [recv(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) and [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)) are returning a byte count on success.

Your [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) will handle them (counting bytes, managing buffers) and use [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) or some other multiplexing syscall. You could find libraries helpful in that case ([libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [libevent](https://libevent.org), etc...)

Be also aware than in 2020 we have [UTF-8 everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/). So even for textual input, some letters (like the Russian Ы or the French à or the last letter of the city  Poznań you are living in...) may take more than one byte. When you send textual information, this adds complexity to your code.

Comment: Well now I thought of sending some metadata and dynamically change the memory of my buffer. Thank you very much, I will look at these that you sent libraries.

Comment: This answer is mostly a bunch of links with no real relevance to the actual problem at hand.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: then why has it been accepted?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Beats me.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: what does "beats me" mean? BTW, I am French. Who is hurting you? Why?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch lol. It's an idiom meaning, roughly, "I have no idea" :) First Google result for the phrase: https://www.talkenglish.com/lessondetails.aspx?ALID=1001

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to keep a count of these bytes yourself, since you always know how many bytes you're writing.

If you have 200KB to send, and you can send 24KB at a time, then it's just (in pseudocode):

```
const int chunkSize = 24*1024;
const int inputSize = 200*1024;

char input[inputSize];   // N.B. VLAs not actually valid C++; this is pseudo-code
int bytesSent = 0;

while (true)
{
   const int bytesRemaining = inputSize - bytesSent;
   const int bytesToSend = std::min(chunkSize, bytesRemaining);
   
   if (bytesToSend == 0)
   {
      // Done!
      break;
   }
   
   const int bytesWritten = send(&input[bytesSent], bytesToSend);
   
   if (bytesWritten == 0)  // I'm assuming 0 written means error; adjust for your API
   {
      // Error! Handle it.
      break;
   }
   
   bytesSent += bytesWritten;
   
   if (bytesSent > inputSize)
   {
      // Something went horribly wrong
      break;
   }
}
```

Easy .

*(In reality you should possibly use some unsigned type like `std::size_t`, not `int`, unless your `send` returns some negative value on error.)*

`bytesToSend` is the key here. You may not want to send a "full" chunk in the last iteration. That's where your extra 16KB came from: your input wasn't an exact multiple of the chunk size.

Comment: Would the downvoter like to leave some suggestions?

Comment: A TCP `send()` will never return 0, it will return either < 0 on failure, or > 0 for number of bytes accepted.  I would also change `while (true)` to `while (bytesSent < inputSize)` and get rid of `if (bytesToSend == 0)`. Also, under the math shown, `if (bytesSent > inputSize)` will never be true, so get rid of that, too: `while (bytesSent < inputSize) { const int bytesToSend = std::min(chunkSize, inputSize - bytesSent); const int bytesWritten = send(&input[bytesSent], bytesToSend); if (bytesWritten < 0) { /* error */ break; } bytesSent += bytesWritten;  }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau That depends on the API you're using, as I said. You're talking about POSIX I guess which is fine. Adjust the logic accordingly, as I indicated. I prefer the conditions laid out as they are. _"`if (bytesSent > inputSize)` will never be true"_ It will if something went horribly wrong and `bytesWritten` was not what it was supposed to be, which is what the comment says and why we give up (`break`) in that case (i.e. don't make assumptions!)

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can write your own answer with your own code style if you like :)

Comment: "*It will if something went horribly wrong*" - what are you imagining can happen exactly? Given the code shown, unless the calling thread's stack memory is corrupted by another thread, bad driver, or hardware failure, then nothing else can cause the `bytesSent > inputSize` condition to happen.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It will if `send` returns something greater than `bytesToSend`, as I said. You don't have to have it if you don't want to, but I like to have error handling in my code, especially at the interface between layers/interfaces/APIs. It makes things more robust and makes bugs easier to track down.

Comment: @ AsteroidsWithWings except that `send()` can't return more than requested, the system guarantees that

Comment: @RemyLebeau It can, if something went horribly wrong. Again, you're making an _assumption_.

Comment: It is not an assumption.  It is documented and proven system design. And over 20 years of personal experience. If something goes "horriby wrong", `send()` will always return < 0, it will never return some wildly inaccurate value > 0 that happens to be greater than the amount requested.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You do not know that. You are making an assumption. You are assuming that `send()` will perform as documented, that nothing goes wrong with it. One last time: feel free to not have this check in your own code, but I like error checking. Thanks for your input! Have a good one.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, in fact I had upvoted it

Comment: Sure you're not. :)